# Combine Apache commands in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, server

If i have two files I want to deny access to on an Apache server - is there a way of combining them instead of writing the same code twice (or more times for other files as well)?

APACHE

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple files use `FilesMatch` like this :

```
<filesMatch "wp-config(\.php)?|xmlrpc(\.php)?">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

That will match `wp-config.php or wp-config` or `xmlrpc.php or xmlrpc` with extension or not

Comment: Hi @MohammedElhag, thanks for the answer.  If I only want the version that includes the .php will I do the opening tag like this:
<filesMatch "wp-config.php?|xmlrpc.php?">

Comment: Just get ? out like this <filesMatch "wp-config(\.php)|xmlrpc(\.php)">

Comment: Glad to help , Thanks